# Faster way of testing a condition in MATLAB

Tags: performance, matlab

I need to run many many tests of the form `a<0` where `a` is a vector (a relatively short one). I am currently doing it with

```
all(v<0)
```

Is there a faster way?

Comment: If your goal is to determine if all elements of `v` are strictly less than zero, I don't know of a faster one.

Comment: Maybe ``any(v>=0)`` could be worth a try. though I am not sure. Maybe one of both is more efficient depending on your ``v``. Other than that: no idea!

Comment: have you tried profiling or using `tic` and `toc`?

Comment: @Shai Sure, that's how I know where my bottleneck is! :)

Comment: @TroyHaskin Basically, I need to select one such element, but there are no such elements I need to know it. Yes. Tough luck, then?

Comment: Post your code to select such element. Maybe the {detection of negative values together with the selection of one} lends itself better to optimization

Comment: @FelixGoldberg If you need to select a particular element from the array then, Luis Mendo's answer is close to what needs to be done.  Namely: [logical](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html) [indexing](http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2008/01/28/logical-indexing/).

Answer (score 2):

Not sure which one will be faster (that may depend on the machine and Matlab version), but here are some alternatives to `all(v<0)`:

```
~any(v>0)
nnz(v>=0)==0 %// Or ~nnz(v>=0)
sum(v>=0)==0 %// Or ~sum(v>=0)
isempty(find(v>0, 1)) %// Or isempty(find(v>0))
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is that the conditional is executed on all elements of the array first, then the condition is tested... That is, for the test "any(v<0)", matlab does the following I believe:

1. Step 1:  compute v<0 for every element of v
2. Step 2:  search through the results of step 1 for a true value

So even if the first element of v is less than zero, the conditional was first computed for all elements, hence wasting a lot of time.  I think this is also true for any of the alternative solutions offered above.

I don't know of a faster way to do it easily, but wish I did.  In some cases, breaking the array v up into smaller chunks and testing incrementally could speed things up, particularly if the condition is common.  For example:

```
function result = anyLessThanZero(v);
w = v(:);
result = true;
for i=1:numel(w)
   if ( w(i) < 0 ) 
      return;
   end
end
result = false;
end
```

but that can be very inefficient if the condition is rare.  (If you were to really do this, there is probably a better way than I illustrate above to handle any condition, not just <0, but I show it this way to make it clear).